# Clear cache in GitHub Actions

Tags: caching, github-actions

I am working on an R package and using GitHub Action (GHA) as a Continuous Integration (CI) provider. I cache R packages (dependencies) by using [`actions/cache`](https://github.com/actions/cache). And now I want to clear all cache. How can I do that?

---

A part of GHA Workflow I use:

```yaml
on: push

name: R-CMD-check

jobs:
  R-CMD-check:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.config.os }}

    name: ${{ matrix.config.os }} (${{ matrix.config.r }})

    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        config:
          # - {os: windows-latest, r: 'devel'}
          - {os: macOS-latest,   r: 'release'}

    env:
      R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS: true
      RSPM: ${{ matrix.config.rspm }}
      GITHUB_PAT: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - uses: r-lib/actions/setup-r@master

      - name: Query dependencies
        run: |
          repos <- c("https://r-hyperspec.github.io/hySpc.pkgs/", getOption("repos"))
          saveRDS("remotes::dev_package_deps(dependencies = TRUE)", ".github/depends.Rds", version = 2)
          writeLines(sprintf("R-%i.%i", getRversion()$major, getRversion()$minor), ".github/R-version")
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Cache R packages
        if: runner.os != 'Windows'
        uses: actions/cache@v1
        with:
          path: ${{ env.R_LIBS_USER }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-1-${{ hashFiles('.github/depends.Rds') }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-1-

      - name: Install dependencies
        run:   remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
        shell: Rscript {0}

      - name: Session info
        run: |
          options(width = 100)
          pkgs <- installed.packages()[, "Package"]
          sessioninfo::session_info(pkgs, include_base = TRUE)
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

Comment: https://github.community/t/how-to-clear-cache-in-github-actions/129038/3

Comment: Clearing cache is [now (June 2022) possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72781422/6309).

Answer (score 171, accepted):

#### Update (July 11, 2023)

As already described in [VonC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76801132/3429133), the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/) now has a dedicated [`cache`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_cache_delete) top-level command:

- List of caches for the current repository:

  ```bash
  $ gh cache list
  ```
- Delete a cache for the current repository by cache ID:

  ```bash
  $ gh cache delete <CACHE_ID>
  ```

#### Update (October 20, 2022)

You can now [manage caches via the UI](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#managing-caches):

```
https://github.com/<OWNER>/<REPO>/actions/caches
```

#### Update (June 27, 2022)

You can now [manage caches via the GitHub Actions Cache API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/cache):

- `GET` list of caches for a repository:

  ```bash
  $ curl \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
      -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
      https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/actions/caches
  ```
- `DELETE` a cache for a repository by cache ID:

  ```bash
  $ curl \
      -X DELETE \
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
      -H "Authorization: token <TOKEN>" \
      https://api.github.com/repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/actions/caches/<CACHE_ID>
  ```

Alternatively, you can also use the GitHub CLI to interact with the API, using the [gh-actions-cache extension](https://github.com/actions/gh-actions-cache).

#### Original Post (November 13, 2020)

As pointed out in the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/2#issuecomment-673493515), two practical workarounds can be used to force the use of a new cache. This is not exactly the same as clearing the current cache (with regards to the [cache usage limits](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#usage-limits-and-eviction-policy)), but it does the job.

In order to do so, you have to change the cache `key` (and any `restore-keys`). Because if the key(s) is/are different, this is considered a cache miss and you start with a new one.

You can change the cache key either by modifying the workflow file directly, e.g., by adding a version number:

```yaml
key: ${{ runner.os }}-mycache-v1-${{ hashFiles(...) }}
```

If you now want to use a new cache, all you have to do is to commit a different version number:

```yaml
key: ${{ runner.os }}-mycache-v2-${{ hashFiles(...) }}
```

If you don't want to modify the workflow file and prefer using the UI, you can abuse [secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets):

```yaml
key: ${{ runner.os }}-mycache-${{ secrets.CACHE_VERSION }}-${{ hashFiles(...) }}
```

Whenever the secret changes, a new cache will be used.

⚠️ **WARNING:** Secrets used for cache keys are ["revealed" in the UI](https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/2#issuecomment-1286988930).

Comment: It also seems like, if you re-run a different workflow on the same cache it get's updated.

Comment: @red-isso what exactly do you mean? If two (or more) different workflows share the same cache?

Comment: @beatngu13 that is a beautifully clever use of secrets for busting caches! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I guess yet another option would be using build parameters, via on/workflow_dispatch/CACHE_VERSION, so that one could set a new version when issuing a build manually.

Comment: @zakmck basically yes, but when the build isn't triggered manually and the cache version input is empty (or defaults to a certain value), then the old/corrupt cache is used again; at least until it is actually evicted. So, one could use this approach to make a quick test if the cache causes build issues. If that is the case, one still has to change the key(s) permanently.

Comment: Thanks again. I think an invalidation option or expiration time are really needed.

Comment: According to [matching a cache key](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/advanced-guides/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#matching-a-cache-key) you could include `${{ runners.os }}-mycache-` in `restore-keys`.

Answer (score 19):

This can be done from GH Actions as well.

```yaml
name: Clear cache

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

permissions:
  actions: write

jobs:
  clear-cache:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Clear cache
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        with:
          script: |
            console.log("About to clear")
            const caches = await github.rest.actions.getActionsCacheList({
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
            })
            for (const cache of caches.data.actions_caches) {
              console.log(cache)
              github.rest.actions.deleteActionsCacheById({
                owner: context.repo.owner,
                repo: context.repo.repo,
                cache_id: cache.id,
              })
            }
            console.log("Clear completed")
```

Make sure it's merged to HEAD branch and trigger it manually from Actions or add your custom triggers.

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, if I understand correctly, this workflow must be in the main branch to be visible in the "Actions" tab to be run the first time.

Comment: Yes, that's how `workflow_dispatch` works.
Any other trigger can be used as well, but only `workflow_dispatch` gives ability to trigger manually.

For manual cache management there is a native UI available now: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#managing-caches

Comment: How can I remove caches based on 'created_at' key? Basically, I'm trying to remove the cache if it was created last week.

Comment: @ÖzerÖzdal Add `if` in the `for` loop and filter by `cache.created_at`. See https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/cache?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-github-actions-caches-for-a-repository for details.

But why would you do that? GitHub will automatically remove them after 7 days of being unused: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#usage-limits-and-eviction-policy

Comment: @lukee yes, I did it by running an if and for loop over cache.created_at. Because I have a package that I generate caches on weekly basis for the following week. So I remove old unused caches from the previous week by running a workflow that runs on daily basis.

Answer (score 11):

You cannot force a clear cache currently and it seems there is an open feature request for it at the moment https://github.com/actions/cache/issues/2. If I were you, I would post the request there as well so that they know that more people want the feature implemented.

A few things to note about the action:

There are not parameters in the action and not even in the toolkit package that this action is build on top of.

Getting deep into the toolkit code they use a cache api url to do all the good stuff. This means we don't even know if that api supports it with the assumption that we try to test it out and see what else it provides by hitting it directly. Here is the line for the api call for which the base url is taken from env ACTIONS_CACHE_URL

https://github.com/actions/toolkit/blob/c2bc747506bf562195a02bd4fdb1ff2a95d8b7ed/packages/cache/src/internal/cacheHttpClient.ts#L44

npm package as reference https://www.npmjs.com/package/@actions/cache

If we take a step back for a moment and go back to the github docs now that we have looked deep into the action/cache code and how it works,

Per the github docs https://docs.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows

There are two things to note,

```
Once you create a cache, you cannot change the contents of an existing 
cache but you can create a new cache with a new key.
```

```
GitHub will remove any cache entries that have not been accessed in over 7 days.
```

Answer (score 11):

Based @beatngu13 [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819132/1322168) I've created Makefile target that remove all cache from Github Actions:

```
GH_REPO ?= ALLATRA-IT/ephyr  # replace with your `org/repo`

# Clear Github Acions usage cache.
#
# Need to install github cli first [https://cli.github.com/] and authorize
#
# Usage:
#   make gh.clear

gh.clear:
    gh api --paginate -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
        /repos/$(GH_REPO)/actions/caches \
        | for ID in `jq '.actions_caches[].id'`; \
          do echo "Deleting $$ID"; \
             gh api --method DELETE /repos/$(GH_REPO)/actions/caches/$$ID | echo; done
```

Need to install [Github CLI](https://cli.github.com/) and [jq tool](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) tools first. After install Github CLI you need to authorize with:

```
gh auth login
```

Comment: Add `--paginate` to delete all caches, not just the first 30: `gh api --paginate -H ...`

Answer (score 7):

One more easy and straightforward way to remove Actions' cache - [Purge cache](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/purge-cache) GH Action.

This action allows the cache of GitHub Actions to be automatically purged based on the last usage and configured TTL (default - 7 days).

**Example:**

```
name: Clear Cache

on:
  schedule:
    - cron: '0 0 * * *' # Runs once a day (https://crontab.guru/once-a-day)
jobs:
  clear:
    name: Clear cache
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: MyAlbum/purge-cache@v1
      with:
      max-age: 604800 # Cache max 7 days since last use (this is the default)
```

The workflow above will run once a day and remove all the cache that was last used more than 7 days ago.

Comment: If I set ```max-age: 1``` will MyAlbum/purge-cache@v1 purge the cache that is stored in GitHub immediately?

Comment: @bekanur98 it should purge all the cache that is older than 1 second

Answer (score 5):

Since you can use the [GitHub CLI `gh`](https://docs.github.com/en/github-cli/github-cli/about-github-cli) in [GitHub Actions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/using-github-cli-in-workflows), you now (July 2023) have with [gh v2.32.0](https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v2.32.0) the new [`gh cache delete`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_cache_delete):

```bash
# Delete a cache by id
$ gh cache delete 1234

# Delete a cache by key
$ gh cache delete cache-key

# Delete a cache by id in a specific repo
$ gh cache delete 1234 --repo cli/cli

# Delete all caches
$ gh cache delete --all
```

---

But, as noted by [DFW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4339010/dfw) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521430/clear-cache-in-github-actions/76801132#comment136913637_76801132):

> How do you identify which cache ID to delete? I'm able to pass that repo flag, but it would be nice to be able to pass a branch or PR flag.
>
> I ended up abandoning using the `gh` CLI as a mean to clear the cache, and instead realized the solution in this answer "[Github actions: How to cache dependencies between workflow runs of different branches?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061281/6309)" was more helpful.
> Most of our builds were branching from a few main branches, so in making the cache live on those base branches, I ended up not needing to delete the caches.

Comment: This feature is super useful, but how do you identify which cache ID to delete? I'm able to pass that repo flag, but it would be nice to be able to pass a branch or PR flag.

Comment: @DFW Good question. Looking at https://github.com/cli/cli/pull/7403/files, I don't see how that would be possible.

Comment: I ended up abandoning using the gh cli means to clear the cache and instead realized the solution in this answer was more helpful. Most of our builds were branching from a few main branches, so in making the cache live on those base branches, I ended up not needing to delete the caches.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71061281/4339010

Comment: @DFW Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibillity.

Answer (score 2):

@GegznaV you can use something like [tmate](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/debugging-with-tmate), and manually clear cache by sshing into a runner.

Comment: Please share more details. How exactly would that work?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a simple commandline solution, the following shell command will also do it. It requires the Github CLI + JQ:

`gh api -H 'Accept: application/vnd.github+json' /repos/realm/realm-kotlin/actions/caches --paginate | jq -r '.actions_caches | .[].key' | sed -e 's/|/%7c/g' -e 's/\[/%5b/g' -e 's/\]/%5d/g' | xargs -I {} sh -c 'gh api --method DELETE -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" /repos/<OWNER>/<REPO>/actions/caches?key={} --silent'`

In this case, I'm using sed to URL encode special characters in the key. I just needed to handle |, [ and ]. Others can be added as needed. See e.g. https://gist.github.com/jaytaylor/5a90c49e0976aadfe0726a847ce58736#file-url_encode-sh-L11

Answer (score 0):

Here's another automated solution similar to @beatngu13's cache key invalidation method.  This one uses a generated timestamp file that gets committed and then used in a `hashFiles(...)` prefix to the cache key.

Included is a set of GNU `Makefile` targets to make using this method very easy: `make clear-github-cache`

**Note:** Make sure each `Makefile` "recipe" section is indented with 1 tab character! StackOverflow converts tabs to spaces in the code block.

```
.github/clear_github_actions_cache:
    date  +%s > .github/clear_github_actions_cache

.PHONY: clean-github-cache-file clear-github-cache
clear-github-cache: clean-github-cache-file .github/clear_github_actions_cache ## Force GitHub Actions Cache key to change for fresh CI run
    git add .github/clear_github_actions_cache
    git commit -m "Clear GitHub Actions Cache @ $$(cat .github/clear_github_actions_cache)"

clean-github-cache-file: ## Remove GitHub Actions Cache timestamp invalidator file.
    [ -f '.github/clear_github_actions_cache' ] && rm -f '.github/clear_github_actions_cache' || true
```

Then, inside the GitHub Actions workflow YAML, add a cache key prefix that uses the hash of this file:

```
      - name: Cache R packages
        if: runner.os != 'Windows'
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ${{ env.R_LIBS_USER }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-${{ runner.arch }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/clear_github_actions_cache') }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/depends.Rds') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-${{ runner.arch }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/clear_github_actions_cache') }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/depends.Rds') }}
            ${{ runner.os }}-${{ runner.arch }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/clear_github_actions_cache') }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/R-version') }}-
            ${{ runner.os }}-${{ runner.arch }}-${{ hashFiles('.github/clear_github_actions_cache') }}-
```

Now just run:

```
make clear-github-cache
```

This generates and commits a file, `.github/clear_github_actions_cache`, with Unix timestamp as contents.  The `hashFiles(...)` cache key prefix uses this and will generate a unique hash of this file as a prefix to the rest of the cache / `restore-key`.

Next time you use `git push`, the cache key will be invalidated... effectively running GitHub Actions with an empty cache.

Answer (score 0):

**keep the last cache** with this bash function (add it to your .bashrc file)

```bash
function gh_clear_old_caches(){

  GH_REPO='your_github_user/your_repository'
  echo "deleting all caches, except the last"
  gh api --paginate -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
    "/repos/${GH_REPO}/actions/caches" \
        | for ID in `jq '.actions_caches | sort_by(.id) | .[:-1][] | .id '`; \
        do echo "Deleting cache id ${ID}"; \
        gh api --method DELETE -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" "/repos/${GH_REPO}/actions/caches/${ID}" | echo; \
    done 
 }
```

name completion works with bash functions as well:

```
gh_<tab>
```

the addition in this one is that jq first sorts the result by id (assuming that the most recent one has the largest).

[:-1] means every id, except the last.