# Github Action failing with R CMD check, using old commit?

Tags: r, github, github-actions

I'm not sure how best to describe this, hence the rather vague title.

I have an [R package](https://github.com/Azure/MicrosoftR) that uses Github Actions to run checks. You can see the workflow file here:

https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/blob/master/.github/workflows/check-standard.yaml

It's basically the same as the check-standard workflow in the [r-lib/actions](https://github.com/r-lib/actions) repo, with some tweaks for my particular requirements. My [latest commit](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/runs/1688860494?check_suite_focus=true) is failing the check for the MacOS build, with this error:

```
Run remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
Error: Error: HTTP error 404.
  Not Found

  Did you spell the repo owner (`hongooi73`) and repo name (`AzureGraph`) correctly?
  - If spelling is correct, check that you have the required permissions to access the repo.
Execution halted
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The step in question is this. It just scans the package's [DESCRIPTION file](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) and installs the dependencies for the package -- all very straightforward.

```
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          remotes::install_deps(dependencies = TRUE)
          remotes::install_cran(c("pkgbuild", "rcmdcheck", "drat"))
        shell: Rscript {0}
```

It looks like it's trying to install a dependency from the hongooi73/AzureGraph repo, which no longer exists. But my [DESCRIPTION file](https://github.com/Azure/Microsoft365R/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) doesn't list hongooi73/AzureGraph as a remote dependency; it uses Azure/AzureGraph of which hongooi73/AzureGraph was a fork. It *used* to refer to hongooi73/AzureGraph, but that was several commits ago. Indeed, the Linux and Windows checks both run without problems so they are clearly using the correct repo location.

What can be causing this failure? And how do I fix it? I've already tried rerunning the workflow, and deleting older workflows.

Comment: You're using `actions/cache` to cache your R libs. Maybe the `key` or the `restore-keys` are not setup correctly and they restore the now "invalid" cache. But I can't really tell because I don't know R and its package management. And I don't know why you don't have the same problem in the other OSs.

Comment: @riQQ That looks like it! The cache key is a combination of the OS, R version and a list of system dependencies. None of these changed from the earlier commit to this one, hence it must be restoring a bad cache. The Windows check succeeded because the cache isn't used there, and the Linux one because the earlier build failed and the cache wasn't created.

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to clear the cache?

Comment: Not really, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521430/clear-cache-in-github-actions

Comment: Well, I changed the cache key and that seems to have fixed the workflow. Pretty clunky though, hopefully they will allow cache clearing at some point

Comment: So maybe you should change your cache key to pick up changes like the one that failed your build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using [`actions/cache`](https://github.com/actions/cache) to cache your R libs. By this you're restoring a cache that might be invalid if your `key` and the `restore-keys` isn't set up properly.

At the moment, there is no direct way to manually clear the cache. For some other options you can check [Clear cache in GitHub Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521430/clear-cache-in-github-actions).

Answer (score 1):

Jan. 2021:

> At the moment, there is no direct way to manually clear the cache

June 2022: Actually, there now is:

> ### [List and delete caches in your Actions workflows](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-06-27-list-and-delete-caches-in-your-actions-workflows/)
>
> You can now get more transparency and control over **[dependency caching](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows)** in your actions workflows.
>
> Actions users who use **[`actions/cache`](https://github.com/actions/cache)** to make jobs faster on GitHub Actions can now use our **[cache list and delete APIs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#cache)** to:
>
> - list all the Actions caches within a repository and sort by specific metadata like cache size, creation time or last accessed time.
> - delete a corrupt or a stale cache entry by providing the cache key or ID.
>
> Learn more about [Managing caching dependencies to speed up workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#managing-caches).

See the [updated answer to "Clear cache in GitHub Actions"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64819132/6309) from [beatngu13](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3429133/beatngu13) for the GitHub API call examples.