# How to handle GitHub Actions deleting its cache after 7 days

Tags: github-actions, pipenv

I have a GitHub Action that runs tests for my Python/Django project. It caches the virtual environment that Pipenv creates. Here's the workflow with nearly everything but the relevant steps commented out/removed:

```yaml
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    services:
      # postgres:

    steps:
      #- uses: actions/checkout@v2
      #- name: Set up Python
      #- name: Install pipenv and coveralls

      - name: Cache pipenv virtualenv
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        id: pipenv-cache
        with:
          path: ~/.pipenv
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-pipenv-v4-${{ hashFiles('**/Pipfile.lock') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-pipenv-v4-

      - name: Install dependencies
        env:
          WORKON_HOME: ~/.pipenv/virtualenvs
          PIPENV_CACHE_DIR: ~/.pipenv/pipcache
        if: steps.pipenv-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: pipenv install --dev

      # Run tests etc.
```

This works fine usually, but because caches are removed after 7 days, if this is run less frequently than that, it can't find the cache and the Install Dependencies step fails with:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/runner/.pipenv/virtualenvs/my-project-CfczyyRI/bin/pip'
```

I then bump the cache key's version number (`v4` above) and the action runs OK.

I thought the `if: steps.pipenv-cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'` would fix this but it doesn't. What am I missing?

Comment: Not familiar with `pipenv` but with many dependency installers they will use the cached data if it’s available (for a speed up) or download if it’s not.  (eg `npm install`)  So there’s no conditional necessary.  Is this not true for `pipenv`?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I think that is true. Most examples I've seen doing this have that conditional though. But then every example I've seen is different in some way...

Comment: That's the correct expression per https://github.com/actions/cache#outputs. But isn't the problem that if the cache wasn't hit `pipenv install --dev` fails, in which case only running it on a cache miss is the exact opposite of the behaviour you want? On a miss you need to do _something else_ to set up the `.pipenv` directory so the other commands can work (and the cache can be refilled).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hmm, I *think* I do want to run `pipenv install --dev` on a cache miss, so it can refill the cache. But for some reason it can't find the directory to install the dependencies in. Maybe I've just rephrased what you said?

Comment: I haven't used pipenv, but how is `.pipenv/virtualenvs/my-project-CfczyyRI/bin/pip` filled to begin with?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I think, first time it's run, the "Install dependencies" step creates the virtualenv at that location. I am honestly hazy about *exactly* how a pipenv (or any other package manager) environment and dependencies are related to the cache. I feel there's some bit of "magic" in there that I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

- First alternative: using a separate workflow, with a [`schedule` trigger event](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#schedule), you can run workflows on a recurring schedule.
  That way, you force a refresh of those dependencies in the workflow cache.
- Second alternative: use `github.rest.actions.getActionsCacheList` from [`actions/github-script`](https://github.com/actions/github-script) (as [seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73556714/6309)) again in a separate workflow, just to read said cache, and check if it still disappear after 7 days.
- Third alternative: check if reading the cache through the new Web UI is enough to force a refresh.

---

On that third point (Oct. 2022):

> ### [Manage caches in your Actions workflows from Web Interface](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-20-manage-caches-in-your-actions-workflows-from-web-interface/)
>
> Caching dependencies and other commonly reused files enables developers to speed up their GitHub Actions workflows and make them more efficient.
>
> We have now enabled [Cache Management from the web interface](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows#managing-caches) to enable developers to get more transparency and control over their cache usage within their GitHub repositories.
>
> Actions users who use [`actions/cache`](https://github.com/actions/cache) can now:
>
> - View a list of all cache entries for a repository.
> - Filter and sort the list of caches using specific metadata such as cache size, creation time, or last accessed time.
> - Delete a corrupt or a stale cache entry
> - Monitor aggregate cache usage for repositories and organizations.
>
> In addition to the Cache Management UX that we have now enabled, you could also use our [Cache APIs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/cache) or install the [GitHub CLI extension for Actions cache](https://github.com/actions/gh-actions-cache#readme) to manage your caches from your terminal.
>
> Learn more about [dependency caching to speed up your Actions workflows](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/caching-dependencies-to-speed-up-workflows).