# How to clear GitHub caches in workflow using gh?

Tags: caching, github-actions

I want to periodically remove all GitHub caches for my project using a workflow action. While this has been [discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63521430/clear-cache-in-github-actions/76801132#76801132), the GitHub toolkit has evolved and the proposed solutions seem rather messy and hard to understand.

The project is private and its organization on the free plan, if that's of relevance.

I figured it should be possible to run [`gh cache delete --all`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_cache_delete) in the workflow. So I devised the following workflow:

```yaml
name: Clear all GitHub actions caches
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 4 * * 0"
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  clear-github-caches:
    name: Clear all GitHub action caches
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    steps:
      - run: |
          gh repo list
          gh cache delete --all --repo me/my-project
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

However, when I run it, it fails with:

```
me/my-project   <description>   private 2023-11-05T17:17:15Z
HTTP 403: Resource not accessible by integration (https://api.github.com/repos/me/my-project/actions/caches?per_page=100)
```

I also tried to use a local work copy by adding:

```yaml
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
```

but this did not change anything.

Do I need a different [permission](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/assigning-permissions-to-jobs) than "contents: write"? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: The above `gh cache delete` [docs](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_cache_delete) mentions "**Deletion requires authorization with the "repo" scope.**" which means you need to create a PAT for this with `repo` scope as the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have it. And, you do need the checkout step also (or you'll have to specify the repo using `--repo` flag with `gh` commands).

Comment: @Azeem Thanks, that did the trick. If you post this as answer, I can make it the accepted one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gh cache delete` [docs](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_cache_delete) mentions:

> Deletion requires authorization with the "repo" scope.

which means you need to create a PAT (Personal Access Token) for this with `repo` scope as the default `GITHUB_TOKEN` doesn't have it.

And, you do need the checkout step also (or you'll have to specify the repo using `--repo` flag with `gh` commands).

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual action I ended up with:

```yaml
name: Clear all GitHub actions caches
on:
  schedule:
    - cron: "0 4 * * 0"  # run automatically each Sunday 4:00 UTC
  workflow_dispatch:     # allow to run manually 

jobs:
  clear-github-caches:
    name: Clear all GitHub action caches
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Clear all caches
        run: gh cache delete --all --repo me/my-project  # TODO: Use your project.
        env:
          # This token requires the "repo" scope.
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.ACTION_CLEAR_CACHES_TOKEN }}
```

Change the argument for `--repo` to your project.

To provide the token for this, [create a personal access token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token) with the "repo" permission enabled. Then [add a GitHub secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions) named `ACTION_CLEAR_CACHES_TOKEN` and use the token as content.